# Knowing why a question was closed

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I'd like to know why this question: [Using Baire Category Theorem to prove $\mathbb{R}^2\not\cong\mathbb{R}^3$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970426/use-baire-category-theorem-to-prove-mathbb-r-2-and-mathbb-r3-are-not-ho) was closed. I thought it was very interesting and I really want to see a prove of it!

In this scenarios, is there a place to know exactly why was a question closed?

Comment: Note... now re-opened, after being re-worded by a third party.

Comment: Thanks @GEdgar.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is a place to find why a question is closed: it's the notice under the question with yellowish background. It looks like this:

[image]

Some of the words in the notice appear in blue font, suggesting that they are  links leading to more information on the subject.

Comment: It was put on hold because he didnt say what he tried, is that correct?

Comment: @JonasGomes It was closed because there's no context.  Also, "what I tried" $\subseteq$ "context."  That is, there are other ways of providing context besides attempted solutions; for example, one could describe techniques that solved similar problems yet cannot solve this problem.

Comment: Or the asker could just give some motivation for the problem, even if they have no idea how to solve it. Of course, some people may ask about questions that they can't solve, but at least they can say what they were thinking about when they came up with the question (e.g., http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12229/how-did-douglas-adams-choose-the-ultimate-question ), why it is interesting, etc. Of course, if they didn't come up with the question because it's homework, then saying what they tried may be the best option - for the site *and* for them to understand the homework. @Jonas Gomes

Answer (score 4):

(IMO) The posting was closed because it was assigning the problem to MSE. Using the site to crowdsource mathematical work is an activity many of us strongly dislike. (both for its own demerit, and for the consequences that welcoming such activity is likely to bring)